# Jupyter Notebook not showing in Coder Code-Server

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, code-server, coder

I set up Coder (with code-server) via a docker-compose.yml but encounter the problem, that Jupyter Notebooks can not be displayed or used is VSCode.

How the issue looks like with no cells showing up despite being present as seen in the outline on the left:
[image]

docker-compose.yml snippet according to official exmaple: https://github.com/coder/coder/blob/main/docker-compose.yaml

```
  # VS Code Server
  coder:
    image: ghcr.io/coder/coder:latest
    ports:
      - "7080:7080"
    environment:
      CODER_PG_CONNECTION_URL: "postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER:-username}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-password}@database/${POSTGRES_DB:-coder}?sslmode=disable"
      CODER_ADDRESS: "0.0.0.0:7080"
      CODER_ACCESS_URL: "http://mydomain:7080"
    group_add:
      - "134"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
  database:
    image: "postgres:14.2"
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-username} # The PostgreSQL user (useful to connect to the database)
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-password} # The PostgreSQL password (useful to connect to the database)
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-coder} # The PostgreSQL default database (automatically created at first launch)
    volumes:
      - coder_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER:-username} -d ${POSTGRES_DB:-coder}",
        ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

My coder template to create the workspace:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    coder = {
      source  = "coder/coder"
      version = "0.6.10"
    }
    docker = {
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "~> 2.20.2"
    }
  }
}

data "coder_provisioner" "me" {
}

provider "docker" {
}

data "coder_workspace" "me" {
}

resource "coder_agent" "main" {
  arch = data.coder_provisioner.me.arch
  os   = "linux"

  login_before_ready     = false
  startup_script_timeout = 180
  startup_script         = <<-EOT
    set -e

    # install and start code-server
    curl -fsSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh -s -- --method=standalone --prefix=/tmp/code-server --version 4.8.3
    /tmp/code-server/bin/code-server --auth none --port 13337 >/tmp/code-server.log 2>&1 &
  EOT
}

resource "coder_app" "code-server" {
  agent_id     = coder_agent.main.id
  slug         = "code-server"
  display_name = "code-server"
  url          = "http://localhost:13337/?folder=/home/${data.coder_workspace.me.owner}"
  icon         = "/icon/code.svg"
  subdomain    = false
  share        = "owner"

  healthcheck {
    url       = "http://localhost:13337/healthz"
    interval  = 3
    threshold = 10
  }

}

variable "docker_image" {
  description = "What Docker image would you like to use for your workspace?"
  default     = "base"

  # List of images available for the user to choose from.
  # Delete this condition to give users free text input.
  validation {
    condition     = contains(["base", "java", "node", "ptr"], var.docker_image)
    error_message = "Invalid Docker image!"
  }

  # Prevents admin errors when the image is not found
  validation {
    condition     = fileexists("images/${var.docker_image}.Dockerfile")
    error_message = "Invalid Docker image. The file does not exist in the images directory."
  }
}

resource "docker_volume" "home_volume" {
  name = "coder-${data.coder_workspace.me.owner}-home"
  # Protect the volume from being deleted due to changes in attributes.
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }
  # Add labels in Docker to keep track of orphan resources.
  labels {
    label = "coder.owner"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.owner
  }
  labels {
    label = "coder.owner_id"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.owner_id
  }
  labels {
    label = "coder.workspace_id"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.id
  }
  # This field becomes outdated if the workspace is renamed but can
  # be useful for debugging or cleaning out dangling volumes.
  labels {
    label = "coder.workspace_name_at_creation"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.name
  }
}

resource "docker_volume" "pubmed_embeddings_data" {
  name = "pubmed_embeddings_data"
  # Protect the volume from being deleted due to changes in attributes.
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }
  # Add labels in Docker to keep track of orphan resources.
  labels {
    label = "coder.owner"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.owner
  }
  labels {
    label = "coder.owner_id"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.owner_id
  }
  labels {
    label = "coder.workspace_id"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.id
  }
  # This field becomes outdated if the workspace is renamed but can
  # be useful for debugging or cleaning out dangling volumes.
  labels {
    label = "coder.workspace_name_at_creation"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.name
  }
}

resource "docker_volume" "shared_coder_data" {
  name = "shared_coder_data"
  # Protect the volume from being deleted due to changes in attributes.
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }
  # Add labels in Docker to keep track of orphan resources.
  labels {
    label = "coder.owner"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.owner
  }
  labels {
    label = "coder.owner_id"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.owner_id
  }
  labels {
    label = "coder.workspace_id"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.id
  }
  # This field becomes outdated if the workspace is renamed but can
  # be useful for debugging or cleaning out dangling volumes.
  labels {
    label = "coder.workspace_name_at_creation"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.name
  }
}


resource "docker_image" "coder_image" {
  name = "coder-base-${data.coder_workspace.me.owner}-${lower(data.coder_workspace.me.name)}"
  build {
    path       = "./images/"
    dockerfile = "${var.docker_image}.Dockerfile"
    tag        = ["coder-${var.docker_image}:v0.2"]
  }

  # Keep alive for other workspaces to use upon deletion
  keep_locally = true
}

resource "docker_container" "workspace" {
  count = data.coder_workspace.me.start_count
  image = docker_image.coder_image.latest
  # Uses lower() to avoid Docker restriction on container names.
  name = "coder-${data.coder_workspace.me.owner}-${lower(data.coder_workspace.me.name)}"
  # Hostname makes the shell more user friendly: coder@my-workspace:~$
  hostname = data.coder_workspace.me.name
  # Use the docker gateway if the access URL is 127.0.0.1
  entrypoint = ["sh", "-c", replace(coder_agent.main.init_script, "/localhost|127\\.0\\.0\\.1/", "host.docker.internal")]
  env        = ["CODER_AGENT_TOKEN=${coder_agent.main.token}"]
  host {
    host = "host.docker.internal"
    ip   = "host-gateway"
  }
  volumes {
    container_path = "/home/${data.coder_workspace.me.owner}/"
    volume_name    = docker_volume.home_volume.name
    read_only      = false
  }
  
  # Add labels in Docker to keep track of orphan resources.
  labels {
    label = "coder.owner"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.owner
  }
  labels {
    label = "coder.owner_id"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.owner_id
  }
  labels {
    label = "coder.workspace_id"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.id
  }
  labels {
    label = "coder.workspace_name"
    value = data.coder_workspace.me.name
  }
}

resource "coder_metadata" "container_info" {
  count       = data.coder_workspace.me.start_count
  resource_id = docker_container.workspace[0].id

  item {
    key   = "image"
    value = var.docker_image
  }
}
```

Adjustments, e.g. in the configurations as mentioned here https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues/3782 or other threads (https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues/4395) do not resolve the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Coder through a proxy at all?

Try checking the web requests panel on the client to see if any requests are failing, that should help narrow it down.

Comment: No I am not, thanks for the advice, I'll check it out!