# Jupyter Notebook cells not showing in code-server running in a docker

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, jupyter, code-server

I want to use Jupyter notebooks in Code-Server in a docker. For whatever reasons I cant get it running and I also have/found no error messages that could help me finding the cause.

Jupyter notebook files (ipynb) can be created and I can also select a valid kernel (usual python environment with ipykernel). Everything looks familiar until this point. However, I cannot create any cells. Just nothing happens when I click the `+ Code` button. If I click `RUN`, I also get no error messages and it seems to execute "empty cells".

My assumption is that something is wrong with the connection between code-server and the ipykernel that is launched inside the docker by the code-server app but without any error message it is still guessing. After searching exhaustively on the Internet, I could only find one other post where the problem looks similar. Since my setup is different Im not sure if it is about the same cause: [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75605766/jupyter-notebook-not-showing-in-coder-code-server)

Hopefully someone of you have an idea of what my mistake is.

Many thanks in advance!!

**MY DOCKERFILE**

```
FROM python:3.9.13

# install some basic stuff
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openssl \
    net-tools \
    git \
    locales \
    dumb-init \
    vim \
    curl \
    wget \
    python3-pip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
# install kernel
RUN pip install ipykernel

# install the latest code-server version
RUN curl -fsSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh


RUN groupadd -g 999 coder && \
    useradd -r -u 999 -g coder coder && \
    mkdir /home/coder && \
    chown coder:coder /home/coder

USER 999:999
EXPOSE 3000
ENV HOME /home/coder
ENV GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM 1

# install VS Code extensions for the user
RUN code-server --install-extension ms-python.python

ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["bash", "-c", "exec code-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000 --auth none /home/coder"]
```

SCREENSHOT
[Code-Server with Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9ed8.png)

- tried different base docker images
- installed/ran successfully Jupyter notebook but the issue in code-server stays
- reloading of code-server and disabling/enabling its extensions

Comment: This is a code-server problem which is still open on github. You can refer to [this answer](https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues/4395#issuecomment-1023546775) and take a chance.

Comment: Thanks for the kick into the right direction!
The issue on GitHub addressed several possible root causes and also mine.

In my case: When starting the docker on my local machine, no HTTPS is served. It seems that HTTPS is required to make jupyter cells in VSCode working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MingJie-MSFT explained, this problem is already known and is caused by the lack of `https://`. See [this issue](https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues/4395#issuecomment-1023506885) and [this issue](https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues/4689#issuecomment-1069268434) on GitHub.

Fortunately, I can provide `https://` in the environment where the Docker is deployed. The problem only occurred on my local computer so far.

So the solution is to provide valid `https://` or use one of the modified images mentioned [here](https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues/4395#issuecomment-1023546775).